# Hibernate inserting NULL into primitive type field

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have an object with a handful of fields, some of which are non-nullable. For non-nullable number types, I use `long`. So for example,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="my_table")
public class MyClass {
  @Column(name="reference_id", nullable=false)
  private long referenceId;
}
```

Both the getter and setter for this object accept only `long`, not `Long`. However, about 1% of the time, when attempting to persist an object that has this `referenceId` field set to some nonzero value, Hibernate will return an error message from MySQL:

```
Column 'reference_id' cannot be null
```

I can't understand how this can happen when the field is type `long`, or when the value is set. Furthermore, attempting to create the exact same object again will succeed.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there some hibernate setting or MySQL setting I need to change?

Comment: Forgot to mention, I have a non-null DB constraint on this field.

Comment: I will suggest to have `referenceId=2` and see if the same thing happens. It's very likely that the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Through some intensive step debugging I was able to determine that the field `referenceId` is actually set to the correct value when the error occurs, so something is happening either at the Hibernate layer or at the MySQL layer.

Comment: Can you enable hibernate.show.sql=true and see whats going on with the sql statements hibernate is generating?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much back and forth, I was able to determine that there was actually a load related bug with my MySQL instance. Switching DB hardware seemed to relieve the problem.